# create a Setup Wizard to Blazor Desktop App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, installation, blazor

How do I create .exe installer for my blazor windows app? I developed one application using blazor for windows with .NET, but I couldn't create an installer to configure location where it will be instaled.

I tried to create a project setup wizard, but I don't know if I configured it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think the [vs installer project extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) is what you need.

We need to create a setup project so that we could use it to create the setup installer for the desktop application. After adding the project as the output, and create the a shortcut, then build the setup project, I'm able to get the msi file in release folder, then double click the file it will start the installation. Then I would get a shortcut for the app in the desktop. See my test result below.

[image]

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOkBUoP54b8) here which might be of help as well.